# Downloading file with Python gives error 699

Tags: python, python-requests, download, zip

On https://www.bibleprotector.com are files available for download (like `TEXT-PCE.zip`).
Manual downloading with a 'right click' works just fine.

However, when trying to download the same file using Python, an `699` error is returned.

```py
import requests
url = 'https://www.bibleprotector.com/TEXT-PCE.zip'
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
open('test.zip', 'wb').write(r.content)
```

Is there a way to download this file using Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm curious as to how the above code worked for you. What results did you get?  When I ran it, I got an html file:

```py
import requests
   url = 'https://www.bibleprotector.com/TEXT-PCE.zip'
   r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
   open('test.zip', 'wb').write(r.content)
```

> $ cat test.zip
> '\n\n\n\n 403 Forbidden\r\n\n\n     \n        403\nForbidden\r\n\n
>
> Access to this resource on the server is denied!
>
> \n\n'

This is how I was able to successfully dload the zip file in your test URL:

```py
import shutil
import os
import requests

# Pretend to be a real browser:
user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/118.0"

hdrs = {'user-agent': user_agent}

url = 'https://www.bibleprotector.com/TEXT-PCE.zip'

# Byte-stream the results
r = requests.get(url, headers = hdrs, stream = True)

# Write the bytes to disk
with open('test.zip','wb') as f:
    shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
```

> $ file test.zip
> test.zip: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract, compression method=deflate

Unzipping gave me the text file `TEXT-PCE.txt` at 4.3MB.

Comment: When I tried my solution a second time, it failed. Your solution seems keep working when I run it multiple times. Why did you choose to use "with open('test.zip','wb') as f: shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)"? Using "open('test.zip', 'wb').write(r.content)" seems to work also.

Comment: Hi @rené, I'm glad that works for you! To answer your question as to why I used `with open(foo, 'wb') as bar:` , that's just my style. Clearly there are other legitimate ways to do it. :-) Also, I'm setting `user-agent` because I _suspect_ that the 403 from the server is an anti-bot measure to limit/prevent scraping, but that's my suspicion.

Comment: Hi @rené, I forgot to mention in the above comment, that one of the things I like about using `with open(foo, '[w,r]') as bar:` is that the file is automatically closed when the thread exits the `with` block. The `with` statement is used for context management. It will close the file regardless of any exceptions. Great technique to use widely.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution: setting `allow_redirects` to `False`.

```py
import requests
url = 'https://www.bibleprotector.com/TEXT-PCE.zip'
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
open('test.zip', 'wb').write(r.content)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the code only worked once. Running it a second time give the same error.